# Why do I get “Value of Key 'Comment' is empty” in my app review?

Tags: application-development

I uploaded a Ubuntu SDK app for review on https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com and the review is pending, because there are errors. One is the following:

```
"desktop_validates (iamonair)": {
"link": "https://askubuntu.com/questions/417377/what-does-desktop-validates-mean/417378",
"text": "did not validate: (ValidationError in file '/tmp/clickreview-aahtrot5/iamonair.desktop': \n- Value of Key 'Comment' is empty )"
}
},
```

In particular, it explains that my `.desktop` is incorrect, that the “Comment” section is incomplete. Though, it seems to me that I did fill this field, as here is my said `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=I am ON AIR
Comment=Listen to the latest episodes of Hardwell's official podcast, Hardwell On Air
Exec=/usr/bin/qmlscene $@ /usr/share/iamonair/iamonair.qml
Icon=images/256.jpg
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Audio;Music;Player
X-Ubuntu-Touch=true
```

I have read some parts of [the FreeDesktop specifications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) as suggested by [another Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417377/what-does-desktop-validates-mean/), but it didn't help. Could you please tell me what I should fix?

Answer (score 1):

I rebuild the application with a more recent version of the Ubuntu SDK (14.04) and now I don't have the error any more.

However, please notice I had an error because of absolute paths in the Exec key. I corrected this too.